# Column name manipulation using Pandas dataframe where no column name is present

Tags: python

I have a dataframe like below:

```
    Sr No   Description Qty     ABC Ltd           XYZ Ltd               
                                W/O Tax W/ Tax    W/O Tax  W/ Tax   
     1      Content_1   10      100      110      98         107    
     2      Content_2   7       150      165      155        170
```

I want to achieve two things:

1. Replace the blank column name with just its previous column name.
   Eg. I want to replace the blank column name (the one with sub heading `W/Tax`) with its previous column name.

So the resultant Dataframe would be

```
   Sr No    Description Qty     ABC Ltd  ABC Ltd   XYZ Ltd  XYZ Ltd    
                                W/O Tax  W/ Tax    W/O Tax  W/ Tax     
     1      Content_1   10      100       110        98      107        
     2      Content_2   7       150       165       155      170
```

2. Once I am successful in point 1, then I want the append the `W/O Tax` and `W/Tax` part to their respective column names. In other words I want the following Dataframe:

   ```
    Sr No  Description   Qty     ABC Ltd_W/O Tax   ABC Ltd_W/Tax    XYZ Ltd_W/O Tax   XYZ Ltd W/Tax
      1     Content_1     10       100                 110               98                 107
      2     Content_2      7       150                 165              155                 170
   ```

I am completely clueless on the above.

Comment: To be clear, that is not a "blank column name", but a hierarchical index ([`MultiIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html)).

Comment: can you give a sample code of your dataframe? instead of just displaying the dataframe

Answer (score -1):

Does this do the trick?

```
dates = ['2016-1-1', '2016-1-2', '2016-1-3']
cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([dates, ['High', 'Low']])
a = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1,6), columns=cols)

    2016-1-1                2016-1-2                2016-1-3
        High    Low         High        Low         High        Low
0   0.921754    -1.646278   -1.530231   -0.068393   0.609982    -0.441507


a.columns = [pref+suf for pref,suf in a.columns]

  2016-1-1High  2016-1-1Low 2016-1-2High 2016-1-2Low 2016-1-3High 2016-1-3Low
0   0.921754    -1.646278   -1.530231    -0.068393   0.609982  -0.441507
```

Comment: Can you please use the above example and elaborate ?

Comment: just editing the columns, might do the trick

Comment: This might not work. Please note that the 1st row is  `W/O Tax  W/ Tax    W/O Tax  W/ Tax ` in the example dataframe.

Comment: so you have tried to do the df.columns = [pref+suf for pref, suf in df.columns] ?

Comment: what does df.columns return when you run it?

Comment: `df.columns.tolist() = ['Sr No' ,'Description', 'Qty', 'ABC Ltd',None,'XYZ Ltd',None]`

Comment: i have assumed you were using MultiIndex. without a code sample of how you have built your df.  
Given the fact that you have provided df.columns.tolist(), i can help with point 1:
`df.columns = [column_name if column_name else df.columns[index-1] for index, column_name in enumerate(df.columns)]`